# Custom boolean filtering in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, filtering

I have a dataframe

```
                  0         1         2         3       Marketcap
0  1.707280  0.666952  0.638515 -0.061126  2.291747     1.71B
1 -1.017134  1.353627  0.618433  0.008279  0.148128     1.82B
2 -0.774057 -0.165566 -0.083345  0.741598 -0.139851      1.1M
3 -0.630724  0.250737  1.308556 -1.040799  1.064456    30.92M
4  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970   476.74k
5  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970        -1
```

Is there some sort of custom filter method, that would let Python know B > M > K?

Say I want to filter, `df[df.Marketcap > 35.00M]`, is there a clever or clean way to do this? 
Having the M or B makes the value very readable and easy to differentiate.

Thank you.

EDIT: Reopened the thread as Max U's answer while excellent seems to produce a pandas bug, which we opened an issue on Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Source DF:**

```
In [176]: df
Out[176]:
                    0         1         2         3 Market Cap
0  1.707280  0.666952  0.638515 -0.061126  2.291747      1.71B
1 -1.017134  1.353627  0.618433  0.008279  0.148128      1.82B
2 -0.774057 -0.165566 -0.083345  0.741598 -0.139851       1.1M
3 -0.630724  0.250737  1.308556 -1.040799  1.064456     30.92M
4  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970    476.74k
5  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970         -1
```

**Solution:**

```
to_replace = ['\d+\s*[Kk]','\d+\s*[Mm]','\d+\s*[Bb]', '-1', 'N/A']
value = [1000,1000000,1000000000, 1, 1]

mask = df.assign(
    f=df['Market Cap'].replace(to_replace, value, regex=True),
    Marketcap=pd.to_numeric(df['Market Cap'].str.replace(r'[^\d\.]', ''), errors='coerce')
).eval("Marketcap * f < 35000000")

df[mask]
```

**Result:**

```
In [178]: df[mask]
Out[178]:
                    0         1         2         3 Market Cap
2 -0.774057 -0.165566 -0.083345  0.741598 -0.139851       1.1M
3 -0.630724  0.250737  1.308556 -1.040799  1.064456     30.92M
4  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970    476.74k
5  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970         -1
```

PS if you want to leave non-numeric values (like `N/A`) in the resulting data set change:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Market Cap'].str.replace(r'[^\d\.]', ''), errors='coerce')
```

to

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Market Cap'].str.replace(r'[^\d\.]', ''), errors='coerce').fillna('0')
```

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it later today as it seems a little complicated and will need some time.   BTW, to get these clean looking output cells (out[178] etc), do you do everything in Ipython via command line and just copy the cells?  I tried copying Jupyter notebook output cells but when I paste it here, it's very untidy.

Comment: @moondra, yes, sorry, i do prefer iPython as I'm kind of console man ;-)

Comment: Hi Max, I have a question about the `mask` portion of the code; The first `f` within `df.assign` creates a new column right?  And the second part, `Marketcap=pd.to_numeric` is also creating a new column? I'm having a little trouble understanding that portion. Thanks!

Comment: @moondra, yes, `f` - is a new column (factor: 1, 1000, 1000000, etc.) and `Marketcap` is a cleaned numeric representation of `Market Cap`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't super clean, but it does the trick and doesn't use any python iteration:

**Code:**

```
# Create a separate column (which you can omit later) that converts 'Marketcap' strings to numbers
df['cap'] = df.loc[df['Marketcap'].str.contains('B'), 'Marketcap'].str.replace('B','').astype(float) * 1000
df['cap'].fillna(df.loc[df['Marketcap'].str.contains('M'), 'Marketcap'].str.replace('M',''), inplace = True)

# For pandas pre-0.20.0 (<May 2017)
print df.ix[df['cap'].astype(float) > 35, :-1]

# For pandas 0.20.0+ (.ix[] deprecated)
print df.iloc[df[df['cap'].astype(float) > 35].index, :-1]

# Or, alternate pandas 0.20.0+ option (thanks @Psidom)
print df[df['cap'].astype(float) > 35].iloc[:,:-1]
```

**Output:**

```
          0         1         2         3         4 Marketcap
0  1.707280  0.666952  0.638515 -0.061126  2.291747     1.71B
1 -1.017134  1.353627  0.618433  0.008279  0.148128     1.82B
4  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970    100.9M
```

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that I also have a `k` (1000's) in my dataframe, so I updated the dataframe in OP, to reflect this. Would you be able to update your code to reflect this?  Thank you so much.

Comment: moondra - @MaxU's solution is much cleaner than mine, I don't see any need to reinvent his wheel.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [44]: df
Out[44]:
          0         1         2         3         4 Marketcap
0  1.707280  0.666952  0.638515 -0.061126  2.291747     1.71B
1 -1.017134  1.353627  0.618433  0.008279  0.148128     1.82B
2 -0.774057 -0.165566 -0.083345  0.741598 -0.139851      1.1M
3 -0.630724  0.250737  1.308556 -1.040799  1.064456    30.92M
4  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970   476.74k
5  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970        -1

In [45]: df[pd.eval(df.Marketcap.replace(['[Kk]','[Mm]','[Bb]'],
                                         ['*10**3','*10**6','*10**9'], regex=True) \
                      .add(' < 35*10**6'))]
Out[45]:
          0         1         2         3         4 Marketcap
2 -0.774057 -0.165566 -0.083345  0.741598 -0.139851      1.1M
3 -0.630724  0.250737  1.308556 -1.040799  1.064456    30.92M
4  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970   476.74k
5  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970        -1
```

---

I'd do it this way:

```
In [13]: df[pd.eval(df.Marketcap.replace(['M','B'],['','*1000'], regex=True).add(' > 35'))]
Out[13]:
          0         1         2         3         4 Marketcap
0  1.707280  0.666952  0.638515 -0.061126  2.291747     1.71B
1 -1.017134  1.353627  0.618433  0.008279  0.148128     1.82B
4  2.029370  0.899612  0.261146  1.474148 -1.663970    100.9M
```

Explanation:

```
In [14]: df.Marketcap.replace(['M','B'],['','*1000'], regex=True)
Out[14]:
0    1.71*1000
1    1.82*1000
2          1.1
3        30.92
4        100.9
Name: Marketcap, dtype: object

In [15]: df.Marketcap.replace(['M','B'],['','*1000'], regex=True).add(' > 35')
Out[15]:
0    1.71*1000 > 35
1    1.82*1000 > 35
2          1.1 > 35
3        30.92 > 35
4        100.9 > 35
Name: Marketcap, dtype: object

In [16]: pd.eval(df.Marketcap.replace(['M','B'],['','*1000'], regex=True).add(' > 35'))
Out[16]: array([True, True, False, False, True], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Why do you have `regex = True` enabled?

Comment: If I have `regex = True`, I'm running into this error; `'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'` . If I turn it off I'm running into an different error, which I posted in the OP as an image. Any ideas about the errors?

Comment: @moondra, what is your Pandas version?

Comment: @moondra, we need `regex=True`, because otherwise the "multi-replace" (when we specify a list of replacements) will not work - it will not replace anything

Comment: my Pandas version is '0.19.2'

Comment: @moondra, that's weird. Do you have any NaN's/None's or empty strings in the `Marketcap` column?

Comment: I ran this line and only found these two; the `k` I took care of incorporating 'k' in the code. I will update the OP so you can see everything clearly.

Comment: @moondra, aha, got it. What do we do with `k`? Do you want to remove it or to ignore those rows or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw my next line,(under the image) but I tried dividing 'k' by a 1000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143714/discussion-between-maxu-and-moondra).

Comment: Okay, I submitted it as a bug. Hopefully they will take a look at it. Thank you for your help  =)

Comment: @moondra, good job! I've added a [comment there](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16289) for reproducing this issue...

Comment: Thanks for that comment, that should help.

Comment: ( I don't want to take away, your points, but going to reopen the thread to look for other viable answers)